# Control shooting frequency when the button to shoot is pressed?

Tags: python, pygame

The bullets shoot all at once when the button is pressed but I only want them to shoot once every 0.5 seconds if the button to shoot is pressed.

I have tried to import time and delay the bullets but it just delayed pygame itself.

Is there any way that I can regulate how frequent the character can shoot?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption("First project")
run = True
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)


def drawbg():
    pygame.display.update()
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)


class person(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.IsJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.left = False
        self.right = False

class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, colour, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.colour = colour
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 7 * facing

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.colour, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

man = person(100, 400, 50, 60)
man2 = person(500, 400, 50, 60)
bullets = []

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(25)

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 700 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_g]:
        if man.left:
            facing = -1
        else:
            facing = 1
        if len(bullets) < 5:
            bullets.append(projectile(man.x + man.width//2, round(man.y + man.height/2), 6, (100, 100, 100), facing))


    if keys[pygame.K_p]:
        if man2.left:
            facing = -1
        else:
            facing = 1
        if len(bullets) < 50:
            bullets.append(projectile(man2.x + man2.width//2, round(man2.y + man2.height/2), 6, (0, 0, 0), facing))

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man2.x > man2.vel:
        man2.x -= man2.vel
        man2.left = True
        man2.right = False

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man2.x < 700 - man2.width - man2.vel:
        man2.x += man2.vel
        man2.right = True
        man2.left = False

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and man.x < 700 - man.width - man.vel:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False


    if not man.IsJump and keys[pygame.K_w]:
        man.IsJump = True
        man.JumpCount = 10

    if man.IsJump:
        if man.JumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.JumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.JumpCount ** 2) / 2 * neg
            man.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.IsJump = False
            man.JumpCount = 10

    if not man2.IsJump and keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        man2.IsJump = True
        man2.JumpCount = 10

    if man2.IsJump:
        if man2.JumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man2.JumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man2.y -= (man2.JumpCount ** 2) / 2 * neg
            man2.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man2.IsJump = False
            man2.JumpCount = 10

    pygame.draw.rect(win, red, (man.x, man.y, man.width, man.height))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, green, (man2.x, man2.y, man2.width, man2.height))
    drawbg()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You could maintain a timestamp. You update it everytime a bullet is fired and you only allow a bullet to be fired if the timestamp is at least 0.5 seconds old.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for the time the last bullet was fired.

initiate the variable by:

```
import time

last_bullet = time.time()
```

then change your code to:

```
if len(bullets) < 5:
    if time.time() - last_bullet > 0.5:
        last_bullet = time.time()
        bullets.append(projectile(man.x + man.width//2, round(man.y + man.height/2), 6, (100, 100, 100), facing))
```

Comment: That's the way to do it. If you don't want to use the time module, you could also use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` instead (but it works in milliseconds, not seconds).